# Is there a G-code to get power supply state?

Tags: marlin, reprap, g-code, switching-power-supply

I'm using `M80` and `M81` G-codes to power on/off power supply.

Is there a G-code to know the actual state of the power supply?

Comment: While there is no dedicated command for this, there may be some options.  Can you describe your hardware?
Are you using a stock printer or a custom?
What are you turning off with the M81?
Are you just turning off the 12V and leaving 5V board supply on?
What boardset are you running?  RAMPS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks! I confirmed that there isn't such a G-code.
I sent a pull request to make this posible:
https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/pull/6671

Now, "M80 S" reports the current state of the power supply.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see one at http://reprap.org/wiki/G-code so it's probably safest to set the power supply to the state you want.